# Inertia Laravel Vue js Sorting on Table

Tags: php, vuejs3, laravel-8, inertiajs

I have been trying to sort the table after fetching it from the database and I could able to sort and search but with a repetitive code. Can anyone help me with how to refactor this code?

```
if(request()->has(['field', 'direction']))
            {
            
            $company = Company::query()
            ->orwhere('code', 'LIKE', '%'.request('search').'%')
            ->orwhere('description', 'LIKE', '%'.request('search').'%')
            ->orwhere('email', 'LIKE', '%'.request('search').'%')
            ->orderBy(request('field'), request('direction'))

            ->with(['user' => function ($query) {
                $query->select('id','name', 'email');
            }])->paginate(5); 

            }


            else
            {
            
            $company = Company::query()
            ->orwhere('code', 'LIKE', '%'.request('search').'%')
            ->orwhere('description', 'LIKE', '%'.request('search').'%')
            ->orwhere('email', 'LIKE', '%'.request('search').'%')
            ->with(['user' => function ($query) {
                $query->select('id','name', 'email');
            }])->paginate(5); 

            }
```

If the request has a `field` value and `direction` then it's executing a block or it's executing another block. How can I refactor the code in a single block?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [the query builder `when` method](https://laravel.com/docs/queries#conditional-clauses).

Using a conditional clause, you can write your code sample like this:

```php
$company = Company::query()
    ->where('code', 'LIKE', '%' . request('search') . '%')
    ->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', '%' . request('search') . '%')
    ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', '%' . request('search') . '%')
    ->with([
        'user' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('id', 'name', 'email');
        }
    ])
    ->when(
        request()->has(['field', 'direction']),
        fn($query) => $query->orderBy(request('field'), request('direction'))
    )
    ->paginate(5);
```